# MIMO antennas and Resource Block

Tags: mimo

Assuming there are 4 transmit antennas, do these four antennas share the bandwidth?
In other words, I wonder if these four antennas use one resource grid.

Answer (score 1):

yes. That's what MIMO does. That's *literally* why you want to use MIMO, because different antennas experience different channels for the same frequency.